# How can I turn off Gradle error popup notifications on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, gradle

I am developing `gradle` scripts on Ubuntu.
Whenever an error occurs one or more of these kind of popups appear:

[image: Error Popup]

Does anyone know how to turn these off?
I tried Ubuntu's notification panel without success:

[image: Notification Settings]

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in [this post on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/715308/1022272).  In short, you will need to create a shell script to intercept, classify, and conditionally kill the notifications as they arrive at the notification service.